# How can I trigger angular 1.3 animation with ng-include binding to a partial

Tags: angularjs, animation, angularjs-ng-include

I have an ng-include which is bound to a scope variable.

I can change the included content dynamically through my own 'routing' system using this approach.

However angular animations are fired on enter and leave events and are not triggered simply when the binding changes for the ng-include.

what is the best approach to implementing this, some kind of custom directive that wraps the ng-include behaviour, or is there a simpler way to do this that I'm missing?

Here's the index html

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
     <div ng-include="templateUrl" class="animation" ></div>
     <br/><form> 
     <button  ng-click="swapTemplate()">Swap</button> 
     </form>
  </body>
```

and the controller code

```
 $scope.templateUrl = 'page2.html';

  $scope.swapTemplate = function() { 
    if($scope.templateUrl === 'page1.html'){
      $scope.templateUrl = 'page2.html';
    }
    else {
      $scope.templateUrl = 'page1.html';
    }
  }
```

And the plnk http://plnkr.co/edit/Oh1vKi0DCxj95qO1J23x

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `angular-animate.js` file

```
<script data-require="angular-animate@*" data-semver="1.2.13" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
```

add `ngAnimate` module in to main module

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngAnimate']);
```

here  is the demo [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lUIbKQFmmegEEZUfqNHU?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks, I had the angular library integrated and correctly injected, so the problem must lie elsewhere in my code.